# Java heap space memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jvm, out-of-memory

I'am solving JVM memory leak,this is what i know so far:

- leak happens in heap space.
- after GC oldGeneration space is not reclaimed, or reclaimed very little.[image]

As you can see old generation space fills you very quickly.

Does anyone knows how which objects allocates memory? Or have some hints how to solve it?

Comment: Do you have a heap dump to work with?

Comment: Yes, I can dump it. Problem I dont really know what I should look for?

Comment: Check AnarchoEnte's response. You will want some specialized editor (Eclipse MAT is one example) to analyze the dump and see which objects are represented the most, which should give you a hint on where the leak might be.

Comment: Unclosed streams or huge static caches are common structures to look for.

Comment: A space of 500MB getting filled within thirteen hours is not “very quickly”. Apparently, your application’s heap has been configured to allow the JVM to utilize 700MB for the old generation and you can’t assume that there is a leak just because the JVM uses as much memory as has been configured. The stronger indicators are a) when you can state a reason why you application shouldn’t use 700MB or b) when actual allocation failures happen after “Feb 5, 14:00”, when the old generation can not get expanded anymore…

Comment: I agree with Holger, but I think that there is a memory leak because the OldGen can not be cleaned anymore and get filled constantly. Another possibility is that you are running a long task which needs more memory than available. In that case you can try to configure more memory with -Xmx Parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to create a HeapDump (e. g. via JVisualVM) to check which objects are still referenced. Via Eclipse MAT you can analyze this dump. Only objects which are not referenced any more are automatically removed by the GC.